# react-native project creation gives node-pre-gyp Hit error socket hang up error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am trying to create a `react-native` project, however, it throws the error while installing `node-pre-gyp` module.

I am using Mac, I also tried installed the `node-pre-gyp` globally. However, getting the same error.

```
➜  mobile react-native init Demo
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/gaurang.shah/Documents/personal/code/mobile/Demo
Installing react-native...
Consider installing yarn to make this faster: https://yarnpkg.com

> fsevents@1.2.7 install /Users/gaurang.shah/Documents/personal/code/mobile/Demo/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.7 and node@11.10.0 (node-v67 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error socket hang up
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node
  COPY /Users/gaurang.shah/Documents/personal/code/mobile/Demo/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64/fse.node
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN react-native@0.58.5 requires a peer of react@16.6.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ react-native@0.58.5
added 733 packages from 381 contributors and audited 27744 packages in 899.043s
found 11 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to incompatibility of old installed packages within `node_modules` with the newer version of npm. Try removing the `node_modules` directory using `rm -rf Demo/node_modules`, and retry `mobile react-native init Demo`.